# error: 405 Method Not Allowed Using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, openweathermap

I'm building a Weather Journal application using Node, and I keep getting this error when the POST route code is getting executed. My GET function is executed well and I retrieve the data needed then this error stops the rest of the process(saving data/updating the UI/etc)..
here is the piece of code causing the problem:

```
async function postData(url="",data={}){
   console.log(data);
   const res= await fetch (url, { //this method not allowed idk why.
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
       'content-type':'application/JSON'
     },
     credentials: 'same-origin',
     body: JSON.stringify(data)
   });
   try{
     const finalData= await res.json();
     console.log(finalData);
     return finalData;
   } catch(error) {
       console.log("error", error);
   }
}
```

Here is the server-side code after setting up express/cors/body-parser

```
app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Now listening on port ${port}`);
    });

    app.get('/all', function (req,res) {
        res.send(projectData)
    });
    
    app.post('/add', function(req,res){
        console.log(req.body);
        newEntry={
            date: req.body.date,
            temp: req.body.temp,
            content: req.body.content
        }
        projectData.push(newEntry);
    });
```

I tried to use different pieces of code I found online on the same topic but it all ended up giving me the same error, tried googling as well but didn't really help. I'm also a beginner with node, app building, or working with servers so I'm really not sure if what I stated here is gonna make it clear for y'all to help.

Comment: The server handling `url` is returning that error. We have no idea why.

Comment: we need more context here. If you built the API, we need to see the post endpoint code and the request sent.

Comment: Because, you are not sending request to openweathmap API endpoint.

Comment: The server side code shown seems completely unrelated to the `postData` function. We don't know what URL you're calling, how it's being called, what `postData` has to do with anything, how OpenWeatherMap is involved, etc. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.